# How to check mysql version inside mysql docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to check it without getting inside the container?
something like

```
docker container exec -it <container name> ....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the version using Docker inspect.

```
docker inspect mysql8 | grep MYSQL_MAJOR

#Or to print version plus major both

docker inspect mysql8 | grep MYSQL_
```

or without running the container

```
docker run -it mysql8 bash -c "printenv | grep MYSQL_VERSION"
```

Or if the container is already running

```
docker exec mysql bash -c "mysql -V"
```

Comment: I might as well delete my answer if you're going to put it into yours?

Comment: @Nordle ah I was editing the answer at that time :D

Comment: Ah sorry if that sounded negative, I mean either you remove it from yours or I will delete mine, there's not point having 2 of the same answers :)

Comment: we just need to run the command so allocating `tty` not required.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `exec` to run commands against a container:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bash -c "mysql -V"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get Container ID:

> docker ps

Ex image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0zGy.png)

3. Remote to docker & using bash in it:

> docker exec -it <container_name> bash

4. Input command:

> mysql -V